# Weblogic FileNotFoundException Too many open files

Tags: java, unix, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We ran into an issue lately when trying to access weblogic console in Unix server, we would get:

> Error 503--Service Unavailable

And in the log file it would state:

> Caused By:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/weblogic1036/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/co>nsoleapp/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml (Too many open files)

After some googling I ran into a solution that stated that the /etc/security/limits.conf file dictates the number of files a process can hold open, https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf specifically **nofile** and it needs to be raised.
I also compared it to another server we have where the weblogic consoles do work where the nofile line was existing with a high enough value.

We added the two lines as well in the server where the issues happens:

* soft nofile 65536

* hard nofile 65536

And indeed it solved the issue and the console worked.
but now for some reason after restarting this weblogic the issue returned, and when checking the limits of the weblogic process we see that it has the old default value of 1024 files:

`cat /proc/32203/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files
...`

1. A different weblogic console on the same server does work (after the fix mind you) and returns a "Max open files" of 65536
2. the limits file was not changed and still holds the new nofile value

Any idea why the issue could have returned ? it looks like the server for some reason "forgot" or "cleared" the max open files value for this specific weblogic after restarting it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2156103 does this help?

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) you shared quotes it is not permanent.

> Also, please note that all limit settings are set per login. They are
>   not global, nor are they permanent; existing only for the duration of
>   the session.
>
> In the limits configuration file, the '#' character introduces a
>   comment - after which the rest of the line is ignored.

Try as stated in comment

```
ulimit -n 65536
```